# How to save colors chosen by user between views and refreshing page?

Tags: angular

My question is following:

How to keep colors chosen by user between views and refreshing. I mean that in some view (it has service, controller and template) user can choose three colors from list and I display his choice under the list.

However, after back/next or another navigation with application's button these colors are lost.  Moreover, I would like to this choice be able to save refreshing (f5) page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You will need a shared service or a redux setup with some help from Browsers local storage .

When the User selects the colour from the drop down the `selected value` has to added to the shared service or dispatched to the store and there after adding the value to the store you need to add to the browsers localstorage.

Now when the user navigates to the new page all the other components will be notified of the change and will be populated automatically with the new color the user (if selected).

`localStorage.setitem("value",color)`.

Now everytime the user enters the page or refreshes the page you will first check if the localstorage has value then display that if not get it from dropdown [only for the component where the user has option to select from the drop down]. For all the other components you will subscribe from the store or the shared service.

More on how to use shared services [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq).

And ngrx redux setup [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx)